# How to use proguard with android kotlin protobuff

Tags: android, kotlin, grpc

Currently my apps builds ok, but any generated method by proto is not onfuscated, so I keep getting errors like

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Generated message class "cp.j" missing method "getPagination".
```

I don't want to keep from obfustaction all of my data layer. Instead I'm trying to find a way to obfuscated generated protos as well. Here is my proto setup

```
protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = libs.protobuf.protoc.get().toString() }
    plugins {
        id("grpc") { artifact = libs.grpc.java.protoc.get().toString() }
        id("grpckt") { artifact = libs.grpc.kotlin.protoc.get().toString() + ":jdk8@jar" }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach {
            it.plugins {
                id("grpc")
                id("grpckt")
            }
            it.builtins {
                id("kotlin") { option("lite") }
            }
        }
    }
}
```